# Angular *ngFor directive display data on view

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngfor

Working with angular primeng API and following the documentation

```
API [
      id: 1, name:"Test 1", currency: "Euro", status: "Active", date: "4th of April 2008" },
      id: 2, name:"Test 2", currency: "Dollar", status: "Active", date: "12nd of May 2005" }
   ]

 ngOnInit {
   this.col = [
     {field: 'name', header: 'Name'},
     {field: 'currency',  header: 'Currency'},
     {field: 'status', header: 'Status'},
     {field: 'date', header: 'Date'}
   ]
}
```

I can render the data successfully using *ngFor

```
Template.html
<tr>
  <td *ngFor="let col of column">
      {{rowData[col.field]}}
  </td>
<tr>
```

Now I need to make modifications on each data value for example:

*name use uppercase pipe
 *currency  use currency pipe
 *date use date pipe

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columne">
   <ng-container *ngIf="col.field === 'date'"> {{rowData[col.field] | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy'}}</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="col.field === 'currency'"> {{rowData[col.field] | currency:'CAD':'code'}}</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="col.field === 'name'"> {{rowData[col.field] | uppercase}}</ng-container>
</td>
```

How can I modify data being render and for each value modify accordingly

Comment: I'd look into using a component library that offers a table (like angular material). A better way of doing what you have here, if you want your columns to be dynamic in nature like this, would essentially involve rolling your own component library.

Comment: What you could consider using is CDK-table. It has you covered on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could make a marginal improvement by using `ngSwitch` instead:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columne">
    <td [ngSwitch]="col.field">
       <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'date'"> {{rowData[col.field] | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy'}}</ng-container>
       <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'currency'"> {{rowData[col.field] | currency:'CAD':'code'}}</ng-container>
       <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'name'"> {{rowData[col.field] | uppercase}}</ng-container>
       <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>{{rowData[col.field]}}</ng-container
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

but I'd recommend using some component library that offers a table if you need a table with dynamic columns like this. As your other options would essentially involve rolling your own reusable table component, which may be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I hold the same opinion as @bryan60. [Material table can save you from such nightmares](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

```js
const dataSource = [
  {id: 1, name:"Test 1", currency: "Euro", status: "Active", date: "4th of April 2008" },
  {id: 2, name:"Test 2", currency: "Dollar", status: "Active", date: "12nd of May 2005" }
];
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'currency', 'status', 'date'];
```

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="currency">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Currency </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{1 | currency: element.currency}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.status}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is in an example I created using CDK-tables:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bes8zf

It uses a dynamic approach.